# Has anyone been able to get parsley.js working with a minimal custom build of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, webpack, babeljs, parsley.js

parsley.js is the only dependency of my project that depends on jQuery, it would be great to reduce the cost of including jQuery by removing unused jQuery modules.

I have tried building a custom version as outlined on the [jQuery GitHub repo](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery) as well as an [online equivalent](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/) but both failed to run correctly.

When trying to use the custom build I get the following error (*built using Babel and webpack*)

```
import jQuery from './custom-jquery' // local version of custom build
import Parsley from 'parsleyjs'
```

> Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__custom_jquery___default(...)(...).parsley is not a function(…)

Using the jQuery directly from npm works as expected

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
import Parsley from 'parsleyjs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but I imagine that you end up loading your custom jQuery *and* parsley loads the full jQuery nevertheless (which isn't simply using `document.jquery`, check the code)...